# How do I position these 4 elements as depicted below

Tags: html, css

I want to make it so the elements are like in a 2 by 2 square on a page but they just list as 4 in a line here is a JS fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/n2xscyr3/

```css
.w3-card-4 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px 0;
}

.w3-container {
  padding: 0.01em 16px
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>Contact us</h2>
  <p>If you have any questions, complaints or feedback - feel free to contact the team at Potato&trade;.</p>
  <div class="w3-card-4" style="width:15%">
    <img src="" alt="face" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h4><b>Someone</b></h4>
      <p>The title</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="w3-card-4" style="width:15%">
    <img src="" alt="face" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h4><b>Someone</b></h4>
      <p>The title</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="w3-card-4" style="width:15%">
    <img src="" alt="face" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h4><b>Someone</b></h4>
      <p>The title</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="w3-card-4" style="width:15%">
    <img src="" alt="face" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h4><b>Someone</b></h4>
      <p>The title</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried a couple of things but I cant figure it out. I am coding strictly for fun at the moment so I'm not very good at this sort of thing.

Comment: flex and margins might help : https://jsfiddle.net/n2xscyr3/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is by using `float: left;` and then using `clear: left;` on every odd child. Also in order for this method to work, you need to remove the `<br>` tags your have between each `.w3-card-4`.

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n2xscyr3/4/)**

```css
.w3-card-4 {
  box-shadow: 0 6px 6px 0;
  float: left;
}

.w3-card-4:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left;
}

.w3-container {
  padding: 0.01em 16px
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-container">
  <h2>Contact us</h2>
  <p>If you have any questions, complaints or feedback - feel free to contact the team at Potato&trade;.</p>
  <div class="w3-card-4" style="width:15%">
    <img src="" alt="face" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h4><b>Someone</b></h4>
      <p>The title</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-card-4" style="width:15%">
    <img src="" alt="face" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h4><b>Someone</b></h4>
      <p>The title</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-card-4" style="width:15%">
    <img src="" alt="face" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h4><b>Someone</b></h4>
      <p>The title</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-card-4" style="width:15%">
    <img src="" alt="face" style="width:100%">
    <div class="w3-container">
      <h4><b>Someone</b></h4>
      <p>The title</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is perfect, i will add some padding to space them out thank you!

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/n2xscyr3/3/

Make a new container and put 2 items in it adding `display:inline-block;` to the items.